# down-votes and protecting of honest users

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Firstly, I am glad to meet MSE. I'm learning rules of MSE. I try to prove the questions clearly, aesthetically and correctly as possible as. Sometimes I'm sharing my problems with users. I like to help people.

But, someone is attacking to my old/new posts a few days with using down-votes. (from Apr 21/2017 to present). I request that my account be reviewed for protecting of honest users.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a quick review of the downvotes cast against your posts, I should let you know that you (nor anyone else suffering the same rate of downvotes) do not need any protection.

I saw eight recent downvotes when I looked over the span of a month, two of which were on separate answers you gave to a single question, and two or three of which were on posts where you didn't have a question, you were just "sharing" a question for others to solve. I cannot spend time actually evaluating the quality of the answers fully, but I don't see anything particularly bad happening to you.

On this point about question sharing, our forum is not really meant for posing questions you don't have a question about (i.e. sharing them 'for the fun of solving them'.)* You could try puzzling.se for that. So it's understandable why downvotes could have been cast for that reason.

Anyhow, seeing as the scope of the downvoting against you is so tiny and probably half or more of the cases were downvotes cast 'in good faith' such as it is, you really should not be lodging complaints on meta about something like this. The downvoting activity I observed at the time of writing this does not rise above the level of normal background noise of downvotes.

Coordinated and targeted downvoting is already managed by software and moderators, and does a reasonable job of it. In cases like that, targets really are suffering a lot of reputation loss, and it is easy to reverse.

Just keep paying attention to the feedback you get from other community members and skim the FAQs again, and I'm sure in a week you'll probably not be seeing much in the way of downvotes anymore.

- Lots of such questions could conceivably be made into real questions, though, if there is some sensible request for an alternative solution that you are not aware of.

Comment: I'm glad to hear them. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: For some problems, I can finding two (or three) different solution methods. Can't I give separate answers a single questions? Because seperate solutions including different methods. Have a good day.

Comment: @scarface To address your question in isolation: I think it is an OK idea to separate distinct solutions into distinct solution boxes, if their space/complexity requires such a thing. If they are short it would  be better to combine them. Now, if you asked the question knowing the answer, then you may get blowback. This is not really the pattern of use for this site. It may be interpreted as reputation mining if you post a question and then fill it with answers. But there are lots of cases where a person has asked a question not knowing the answer and later answered it, and that is OK.

Comment: @rschwieb I personally disagree with 'our forum is not really meant for "sharing" your own problems'. If anything, this entire forum is based upon sharing your problems so that others can help you with them.

Comment: @mrnovice thanks for your ideas. I understood somethings. If I have a problem including good ideas and if I post it the forum, then some users will punish me. Because I have to be a ''greedy miner''. If I found two solutions of a hard problem, then I must post only one of them. otherwise some users punish me. Because I have to be a ''greedy miner''.

Comment: @mrnovice *this entire forum is based upon sharing your problems so that others can help you with them* I think if you reread what I wrote you'll find we do not disagree at all. I don't know about you, but I think a "person who shares a problem so that others can help them" by definition does not have the solution to their problem. The issue I'm talking about is posing questions you don't have a question about. When someone wants to post a problem that they do not have a question about "for the fun of letting others solve it," I think that's a good fit for puzzing.se.

Comment: And moreover, I'm not really dead set against such posts, but I'm describing the situation as it appears to me. Maybe someone else will support the opposite viewpoint.

Comment: @rschwieb thanks for your ideas. My opinion: Sometimes ( and strongly probable) solvers can find better and/or different approaches from proposer. That is, proposed problem is not only an enjoy.

Comment: @scarface If you can make your question into a reasonable one about asking for an alternative solution you don't know, then that's a sensible question. Of course, you can't just say "does anyone have a solution that isn't X or Y or Z?" But questions like "Is it possible to prove X without using Y's lemma" have appeared frequently in the past.

Comment: @scarface Another type of question that is OK goes something like this: "Here is a theorem ...  Now I have proven it as follows .... but really I think there should be an easier solution involving something like ... Is there a workable approach like that?"  That is a way to attract "better" solutions that you don't know yourself.

Comment: @rschwieb Upon reading your reply, it seems we are in agreement then.